# perl Tie::File to remove lines in text file

Tags: perl

I have the following code to remove lines out of a text file I am using. However, it is not actually removing the lines I want. I have done a lot of testing here and confirmed that it will remove the lines if I get the line number right. However, the `$.` seems to be duplicating the actual line number (as when I print on it, it says there are double the number of lines there actually are!)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# find_company_codes.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Tie::File;

my $split_file = "//server/folder/splits_table.txt";

# remove fields where only MAS has rollcall
my @file;
my @lines;

tie @file, 'Tie::File', $split_file or die $_;

foreach (@file) {

    @lines = split(",",$_);

    next if $lines[0] eq "ESDB Link Processing Reg-Prd-CCD";
    next if $lines[2] ne "";
    next if $lines[3] ne "";
    next if $lines[4] ne "";
    next if $lines[5] ne "";
    next if $lines[6] ne "";

    splice(@file, $.,1);

}

untie @file;
```

p.s. - I know I can use [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f), however, I thought using 'Tie::File` would be a little more straight to the point in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reading from a file, you're iterating over an array. `$.` makes no sense. First, we need to switch to indexes.

```
for (0..$#file) {
    my @fields = split(/,/, $file[$_]);

    next if $fields[0] eq "ESDB Link Processing Reg-Prd-CCD";
    next if $fields[2] ne "";
    next if $fields[3] ne "";
    next if $fields[4] ne "";
    next if $fields[5] ne "";
    next if $fields[6] ne "";

    splice(@file, $_, 1);
}
```

Except that doesn't work either. When you splice, you shift the entire array, so you must not advance the index that turn, and you need to finish the loop one index sooner. Fix:

```
my $i = 0;
while ($i < $#file) {
    my @fields = split(/,/, $file[$i]);

    if (   $fields[0] ne "ESDB Link Processing Reg-Prd-CCD"
        && $fields[2] eq ""
        && $fields[3] eq ""
        && $fields[4] eq ""
        && $fields[5] eq ""
        && $fields[6] eq ""
    ) {
        splice(@file, $i, 1);
    } else {
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

Good, that works, but it's CRAZY SLOW. Every `splice` can cause the rest of the file to be read and rewritten. Yet another inappropriate use of Tie::File! The following will be incredibly faster.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $qfn = "//rosefs19w/sal...";

my @file;
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
        or die("Can't open $qfn: $!\n");
    @file = <$fh>;
}

my $i = 0;
while ($i < $#file) {
    my @fields = split(/,/, $file[$i]);

    if (   $fields[0] ne "ESDB Link Processing Reg-Prd-CCD"
        && $fields[2] eq ""
        && $fields[3] eq ""
        && $fields[4] eq ""
        && $fields[5] eq ""
        && $fields[6] eq ""
    ) {
        splice(@file, $i, 1);
    } else {
        ++$i;
    }
}

{
    open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
        or die("Can't create $qfn: $!\n");
    print $fh @file;
}
```

That's right. Add 3 extra lines of code and remove 2, and your code becomes 100, 1000, 10000 times faster!

Comment: thanks for this. I am experiencing all the pain you just wrote about now. my code has been running for **WAY** too long. I feared that, and found out the hard. Again, thanks for helping and for explaining so nicely.

Comment: That code loads the entire file into memory, but this is trivial to change so it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think this actually moves through the lines of the file. From what I am seeing, this `my @fields = split(/,/, $file[$_]);` keeps referencing the first line of the file (header line).